# WAR file deployment in tomcat server breaks the JS and other resources paths causing layout breaking

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, war

When I deploy a WAR file in a tomcat server, then WAR file name appends in the URL and breaks the JS and HTML files path. This is causing the whole layout to break. How do you get rid of the WAR file name in path?

Comment: I guess it might help showing some breaking examples with focus on the HTML maybe and the WAR structure in your question.